# Referencing a private var from outside scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error: `ReferenceError: e is not defined`

How can I return the value of the `someVal` variable when it is outside the function scope?

```
function doStuff(e, val) {
    console.log(someVal)
    e.preventDefault();
}
$(function() {
    var someVal = 10;
    $('#someBtn').on('click', doStuff(e, someVal));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yftfmw1f/

Comment: you didn't define ```e```

Comment: The second argument to `.on` should be a function: `function() { doStuff(e, someVal);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `.on` should be a function. It will receive the event as an argument, and you can pass that on:

```
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    doStuff(event, someVal);
});
```

You were thinking about it totally backwards. `e` isn't even set until you call `doStuff`, so how can it make sense to refer to it in the function that calls it?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
function doStuff(e, val) {
    console.log(val)
    e.preventDefault();
}

$(function() {
    var someVal = 10;
    $(document).on('click', '#someBtn', function (e) {
       doStuff(e, someVal)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `.on` is a function like the others said. When sharing variables, I personally like to create a set of variables:

```
function doStuff() {
    console.log(this.val);
    this.e.preventDefault();
}

var someVal = 10;
$('#someBtn').on('click', function (e) {//Actually gets e
    var shared = {
        e: e,
        val: someVal
    };
    doStuff.call(shared);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you code should look like. I usually use the data part of the event object e to pass the "this" context of a particular object to the event listener. This allows the use of lambdas instead of just inline functions.

```
function doStuff(e) {
  console.log(e.data)
  e.preventDefault();
}
$(function() {
  var someVal = 10;
  $('#someBtn').on('click', someVal, doStuff);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional `data` parameter.

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

`data` property of the `event` object returns the passed data.

```
function doStuff(event) {
    console.log(event.data); // 10
    event.preventDefault();
}

$(function() {
    var someVal = 10;
    $('#someBtn').on('click', someVal, doStuff);
});
```

The `data` type can be anything, even a function object. If you pass a function you can call it using invocation parameter, i.e. `event.data()`.

Another option is using a closure:

```
function doStuff(param) {
    return function(event) {
        console.log(param); // 10
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
$(function() {
    var someVal = 10;
    $('.someBtn').on('click', doStuff(someVal));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function is needed to create a closure to capture the `someVal` variable so it can be passed to `doStuff`

Here it is working:
http://jsfiddle.net/jmassena/yftfmw1f/9/

```
function doStuff(e, val) {
    console.log(val);
    $('#log').text(val);
    e.preventDefault();
}

$(function() {
    var someVal = 10;
    $('#someBtn').on('click', function(e){
        doStuff(e, someVal);
    });
});
```